# Why does my compiler say that my return statement is missing?

Tags: java, if-statement, return, void

I put in the return statement for both cases, if and else

but it's still says that the return statement is missing

What's wrong with my code?

```
public static getNext(){
    ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>();
    Random dice = new Random();
    int rolls;
    for(int x=0; x<i.length; x++){
        copy.add(i[x]);
    }

    if(copy.size() < 1){
        return "NONE";
    }

    else{
        rolls = dice.nextInt(copy.size());
        return copy.get(rolls);
        copy.remove(rolls);
    }
}
```

Comment: `return copy.get(rolls); copy.remove(rolls);` Come on, really? How should that work?

Comment: `copy.remove(rolls)` is not reachable code; this alone should be erroring out.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you were right. How would I remove the copy.get(rolls) after I return then?

Comment: Put it in a variable, delete it from the `List`, then return it

Comment: `public static getNext(){` <= return type is missing. Your code won't compile unless this is only a copy&paste error.

Comment: Use `return copy.remove(rolls);`. `ArrayList#remove(int index)` returns the element removed.

Comment: I guess the compiler is just spitting out a wrong error message because of the messed up syntax. It should come up with "unreachable code" if it were only that problem. But before that, your method is lacking the return type which also should cause a decent error message for missing return type. So my guess is that there are more syntax issues in that class maybe.

Answer (score 1):

```
else{
        rolls = dice.nextInt(copy.size());
        return copy.get(rolls);
        copy.remove(rolls);   <--- UNREACHABLE
}
```

Your compiler probably missed the return statement due to unreachable line of code after the return.

Also, you haven't declared the returned class. There should be:

```
public static <return type> methodName(<parameters>) {

<body>

}
```

**Q:** How could I remove the copy.get(rolls) after returning it? Is there a way?
**A:** Basically the question is about the concept of functions. Function is a piece of code which performs some logic and then, based on it returns something. Return statement is the last thing that happens in the function.

You can also have a block of code which doesn't return anything, but takes parameters. These are called procedures. Anyway, in Java we call both of them: functions and procedures **methods**.

Comment: How could I remove the copy.get(rolls) after returning it? Is there a way? I didn't put in any parameters because the problem specifically said so.

Comment: @JFreders I'll respond in the answer

Comment: You seem to be confused here.  You don't need to remove anything.  When that method terminates, the collection will go out of scope and be garbage collected, save the one element being returned, assuming the calling code has a reference to it.

Comment: @JFreders you can mark the answer as the solving one by clicking on a gray tick below the answer score.

Comment: @JFreders The compiler error message - was it actually "missing return *statement*" or "missing return *type*" ?

Answer (score 1):

You have some misunderstood in your code :

**First** when you make return the method should return something
**Second** you can't specify any kind of statement after your `return`
**Third** you have to store your return value that you want to remove it and return it in a separate variable

Your code should look like this :

```
public static String getNext() {
//-------------^^------------return type
    ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>();
    Random dice = new Random();
    int rolls;
    for (int x = 0; x < i.length; x++) {
        copy.add(i[x]);
    }

    if (copy.size() < 1) {
        return "NONE";
    } else {
        rolls = dice.nextInt(copy.size());
        String s = copy.get(rolls);//<<----------put the val you want in separate variable
        copy.remove(rolls);//<<-----------remove your val
        return s;//<<-----------return your val
    }
}
```

**Note**

Like @BackSlash mention in comment, it is useless to remove your val from your list, because it will not used after you get out of your method, so if you are using this List in another place you have to declare it outside your method for example :

```
private static ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>();
public static String getNext() {
    //ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>();//<<<-------------useless position
    ....
```

Comment: I would also note that saving a copy of `copy.get(rolls);` and removing it from the list is totally useless, as the list will be destroyed after the method execution ends. `return copy.get(rolls);` is just fine

Comment: mmm, yes this is correct @BackSlash, until the list is inside the method, thank you, i will mention that in my answer if you don't mind

Comment: I don't get why people don't seem to see that the compiler message actually should be another. My conclusion is that there are more syntax flaws in code not shown in the question. That snippet should not cause "missing return statement". It should cause "missing return *type*" and maybe "unreachable code" ...

Comment: i think it depends on the compiler check this https://ideone.com/RcT4QU and in my netbeans IDE it show me this error `incompatible types: unexpected return value` so how did you explain this?

Comment: @YCF_L Well, I am not a "compiler-guy" and you are right, it would most probably depend on which one you are using. Maybe it is also a factor that it is a static method. The point is - in no case should it be "missing return *statement*". I take that as hint that the compiler completely messes up with the syntax structure here and the error message cannot be relied upon. First the obvious errors have to be fixed.

Comment: BTW: Your ideone link , when I clicked it, it said `Main.java:16: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public static getNext() {` - which is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: Yes @Fildor this should be to posted as a question, maybe can others have good explication :), Thank you for your point i appreciate it :)

Comment: Another note: I am not being nit-picky here. All the answers only taking the posted snippet into account won't help completely, if the actual error is outside that code and messing up the message. For example a missing "}" before this code also could cause messages refering to lines in the code - just because that's how compilers work.